# C++ thread-safe, contextual stream-based logging

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging

So I've been writing a logging class for a while now, and I decided to change the class so that it uses streams instead of a function with a string/int parameter combo. Here's what I came up with:
Logger.h:

```
#ifndef __LOG_H
#define __LOG_H
class logger {
    public:
        logger();
        void log ( int mlvl );
        int Llport;
        std::stringstream logstream;
    private:
        void errException( const int &ecode, const int &line, const std::string &file );
        void readCfg();
        void setLogLevel( int llvl );
        pid_t getPID();
        unsigned long getThread();
        std::string tStamp();
        bool writeLog( const std::string &message );
        std::string Lcfgfile;
        std::string Lfile;
        unsigned long Lthread;
        pid_t Lpid;
        int Llvl;
};
extern logger mlog;
#endif
```

logger.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
#include<sstream>
#include"log.h"
#include"ConfigFile.h"
#include"util.h"
#include<unistd.h>
#include<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include<boost/thread.hpp>
#include<time.h>
logger::logger(){
    Lcfgfile="/home/ianc/www/coding/GDAgent/cfg/GDAgent.conf";
    readCfg();
}
std::string logger::tStamp(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime( buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct );
    return buf;
}
void logger::readCfg() {
    cfg::cfg conf( Lcfgfile );
    Llvl = 0;
    if( conf.keyExists( "logfile" ) ){
        Lfile = conf.getValueOfKey<std::string>( "logfile" );
    }
    else {
        Lfile = "/var/log/GDlog";
    }
    if( conf.keyExists( "DebugLevel" ) ) {
        int debuglevel = conf.getValueOfKey<int>( "DebugLevel" );
        std::stringstream d;
        d << debuglevel;
        std::string dd = d.str();
        char dl = dd[0];
        int dlvl = ccInt( dl );
        Llvl = dlvl;
    }
    if( conf.keyExists( "ListenPort" ) ) {
        Llport = conf.getValueOfKey<int>( "ListenPort" );
    }
    else {
        Llport = 8000;
    }
}
unsigned long logger::getThread() {
    std::string threadID = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id() );
    unsigned long threadNumber = 0;
    sscanf( threadID.c_str(), "%lx", &threadNumber );
    return threadNumber;
}
pid_t logger::getPID() {
    Lpid = getpid();
    return Lpid;
}
bool logger::writeLog( const std::string &message ) {
    Lpid = getPID();
    Lthread = getThread();
    std::string ts = tStamp();
    std::ofstream lmsg( Lfile, std::ofstream::app );
    lmsg << ts << " [" << Lpid << "] (" << Lthread << ") " << message;
    lmsg.close();
    return true;
}
void logger::log( int mlvl ) {
    if( mlvl >= Llvl ){
        std::string lin = logstream.str();
        logstream.str("");
        switch( mlvl ) {
            case 0:
                logstream << "[DEBUG] " << lin << std::endl;
                lin = logstream.str();
                writeLog( lin );
                logstream.str("");
                break;
            case 1:
                logstream<< "[INFO] " << lin << std::endl;
                lin = logstream.str();
                writeLog( lin );
                logstream.str("");
                break;
            case 2:
                logstream<< "[WARN] " << lin << std::endl;
                lin = logstream.str();
                writeLog( lin );
                logstream.str("");
                break;
            case 3:
                logstream<< "[ERR] " << lin << std::endl;
                lin = logstream.str();
                writeLog( lin );
                logstream.str("");
                break;
             case 4:
                 logstream<< "[CRITICAL] " << lin << std::endl;
                 lin = logstream.str();
                 writeLog( lin );
                 logstream.str("");
                 break;
             case 5:
                 logstream<< "[EXCEPTION] " << lin << std::endl;
                 lin = logstream.str();
                 logstream.str("");
                 writeLog( lin );
             default:
                 logstream<< "[GENERAL] " << lin << std::endl;
                 lin = logstream.str();
                 writeLog( lin );
                 logstream.str("");
                 writeLog( "[ERROR] Invalid identifier given to logger.\n" );
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
 logger mlog;
```

Basically, I write to a stringstream, then "flush" the stream with a message level. It's all lovely in theory, but in practice...

```
[4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408) 2014-09-04.06:21:23 [4297] (140377696753408)
```

The reason for this is because it's one object instantiated globally across multiple threads - which would be fine if I were passing a parameter to a function, but... the streams keep overwriting each other, resulting in one huge mess and eventually a segfault. I tried instantiating the logger once in each thread and passing it to all functions as a parameter, but I get a cryptic message about copy constructors and synthesized methods for logger(), so then I tried instantiating it once in each module, once in each function, and while the per-module solution (one in every .cpp file that is different from the others) works for the most part, eventually I get an error saying "file *_* (my config file) can't be located!" and the program crashes. 
So my question is, Is there a better way that isn't as clumsy as passing a string to a function, yet still allows me to add context (like a message level) to my log entries?

Comment: If you want to guarantee that a message gets printed you must lock the logging function with a mutex or such. That changes the runtime behaviour of a multithreaded program, obviously, because it's a serialization bottleneck which becomes more critical with more logging (and thus more opportunities for blocking each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the actual logging, which uses the shared resources, in a separate thread.  This thread waits on a shared queue, so the other threads gather their information separately and send that via  the queue to the logging thread.

Advantages are that resources don't need to be shared and the working threads don't have to access external systems for logging (network, disk, terminal).  The downside is that a log just before a crash can be lost, but there are ways to improve this (like waiting for the logger to end when when the severity is critical).

Comment: How would that work? And wouldn't that still have the same problem of the threads overwriting each other's streams?

Comment: This approach is clean but not suitable for debugging fatal errors, because the last logging messages before a fatal error are not printed. Unfortunately they are usually the crucial ones.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: correct, I mentioned that at the end.

Comment: @Oblivious12: gathering the log string should be done independently.

Comment: So something like... rather than threads passing messages to the logging thread, the logger watches the threads?

Comment: @Oblivious12: I don't understand your question.  I propose sending messages to a logger thread possibly losing logs when crashing.  Peter suggests a mutex locking approach with possible performance issues.